# Advanced DataGrid Flex 3 - ItemRenderer and Tree display

Tags: datagrid, flex3, hierarchical

I am using Advanced DataGrid of Flex 3 with hierarchical data. The itemRenderer is a TextInput which accepts numbers. When I enter data into the given field and click the corresponding expand tree icon for the row, I want the amount entered in tree node should get cascaded to its child rows. But I found the nature of advanced DataGrid erroneous.
When I enter data and click on tree icon, the data is not populated in child windows unless i wont take the focus out from the editing control.
I tried using itemEditEnd, itemFocusOut etc but of no use. I have to explicitly click on any of the other columns and then expand tree.
Am I making any mistake anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem, its bit ugly but it works. I had to register two events for textinput as follows
addEventListener(FocusEvent.MOUSE_FOCUS_CHANGE, allocateAmount);

addEventListener(FocusEvent.KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE, allocateAmount);

and then by using IViewCursor I could able to update data.